# Download progress with WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1

Tags: vba, vbscript, winhttp, winhttprequest

Is there a way to find out how much of a GET request has been received? I can't do `Len(.ResponseBody)` until it's complete, so that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I was researching how you could bind to [`IWinHttpRequestEvents`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383925(v=vs.85).aspx). The [`OnResponseDataAvailable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383941(v=vs.85).aspx) event is exactly what you need. It would give you the data as it came in. Then, you could handle it however you like.

Unfortunately, trying to bind to that event interface causes VBScript to crash with a C0000005 GPF. I also found a reference to it crashing in a [different language](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/72839-comobjconnect-crashes-script-on-events/). So, I can't say whether this would work in VBA or VB6 or any other language. Details are discussed in following question.

[WScript.CreateObject crashes Windows Scripting Host when event handler prefix is specified for WinHTTPRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407533/wscript-createobject-crashes-windows-scripting-host-when-event-handler-prefix-is)

---

The alternative is to switch to [`Msxml2.XMLHTTP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759148(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766431(v=vs.85).aspx). These objects come with a property named [`readyState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms761388(v=vs.85).aspx) that will give you some idea of what is happening to the download. It won't give you the current number of bytes downloaded, but it's something.

Additionally, there you can trap the [`onReadyStateChange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759144(v=vs.85).aspx) event, which will let you know when the `readyState` on the object has changed. Microsoft has even provided [sample code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757030(v=vs.85).aspx) for trapping the event.